# Creating a string-array of checked items in checked-list-box

Tags: c#, foreach, checkedlistbox

How can I create an array containing the checked items in a checkedlistbox using foreach loop (or any other way)?

I can't know the number of items in the list.

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox.CheckedItems?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming your using 3.5 or above..

```
object[] items = lb.CheckedItems.OfType<object>().ToArray();
```

And if you are adding a specific type of object to the CheckedListBox then you can replace object with the name of the class you use.

Comment: Can you help me in one more thing please?
I used what you wrote:
string[] fonts = fontBox.CheckedItems.OfType<string>().ToArray();
and than i wanted to write each string in the array on a new line in the rich text box(called fontBox), so i tried:

for (int i = 0; i < fonts.Count(); i++) { fontBox.Text = fonts[i]; }

and i also tried:

foreach (string i in fonts)
            {
                fontBox.Text = i;
            }

but none of them worked

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < fonts.Length; i++)

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working =], and i located another mistake, i told the program to write in the checkedlistbox, not in the rich text box.

Answer (score 2):

Hi i am doing a similar kind of task . But instead of array i am using array list . I used the below code

```
ArrayList errorList = new ArrayList();
errorList = chklbErrorlist.CheckedItems.OfType<object>().ToList();
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<object>` to
>   `System.Collections.ArrayList`

I added the items to the array and then added to the arraylist, It worked. How to add items directly to the araaylist instead of the array

Comment: ArrayList errorList = new ArrayList(chklbErrorlist.CheckedItems.OfType().ToList());