# VB.NET 4.7: Trying to add checked items into XML elements from a CheckedListBox but I get an unexpected output

Tags: xml, vb.net

Hello I am trying to add checked items into XML elements from a CheckedListBox onto an XDocument. I am trying to create it based on the C# code in this question:
 ([C# - creating a string-array of checked items in checked-list-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390122/creating-a-string-array-of-checked-items-in-checked-list-box/53997469#53997469))
 
The variables te and cr are XElements in the problematic code below:

```
Dim b As Object() = CertifiedClasses.CheckedItems.OfType(Of Object).ToArray()

For c As Integer = 0 To b.Count() - 1
    Try
        te.Add(cr)
        cr.Add(CertifiedClasses.CheckedItems.Item(c).ToString())
    Catch ex As IndexOutOfRangeException
        MsgBox("Index out of range")
    End Try
Next
```

The problem I have is when I use this For loop, I want the output to have three subjects `math`, `science`, and `gym` in their own `<mandatory-class>` tag, but I get the following:

```
<teacher xmlns="">
  <firstname>joe</firstname>
  <lastname>schmo</lastname>
  <certification>mathsciencegym</certification>
  <certification>math</certification>
  <certification>mathscience</certification>
</teacher>
```

I have attempted to move `te.Add(cr)` in the whitespace directly after `Dim b` and before `For c` which would end up with simply one tag `<certification>mathsciencegym</certification>`.

Can you find the solution to the problem I am having?

Comment: `b` is defined as an object array. Then your trying to use that as your variable in the loop. Try `For Each ob In b`... Also do you not know the type `OfType(Of Object)`, if so you should define the type you're targeting...

Comment: Welcome, glad to be of help!

Comment: The link you provided isn't using xml.  We need to see the code that created the variable cr to help.  We don't know if you are using an XmlWriter, XmlDocument, or XDocument (or another xml class).

Comment: I am using an XDocument.